# evernote api crud operations

Tags: api, permissions, evernote, endpoints

I'm working on a web project to implement some endpoints to enable CRUD operations for users, I have got the flow working and I'm able to list notebooks in my sandbox account but I can only list notes from the notebook that I choose to share publicly, is this some api keys permission related issue or am I missing something here or is this supposed to happen ? Any help is much appreciated. I am pasting the error below

> /Users/mac/.rbenv/versions/2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/evernote-thrift-1.25.1/lib/Evernote/EDAM/note_store.rb:486:in `recv_findNotesMetadata'
>   /Users/mac/.rbenv/versions/2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/evernote-thrift-1.25.1/lib/Evernote/EDAM/note_store.rb:476:in`findNotesMetadata'
>   /Users/mac/.rbenv/versions/2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/evernote_oauth-0.2.3/lib/evernote_oauth/thrift_client_delegation.rb:16:in `method_missing'
>   /Users/mac/Documents/rails/ms-core/app/api/secm.rb:1158:in`block (3 levels) in '
>   /Users/mac/Documents/rails/ms-core/app/api/secm.rb:1149:in `each'
>   /Users/mac/Documents/rails/ms-core/app/api/secm.rb:1149:in`block (2 levels) in '
>   /Users/mac/Documents/rails/ms-core/app/api/helpers.rb:378:in `return_elegant_errors'

the code used to grab notes from notebook is

> ```
>   note_store ||= client.note_store
>     notebooks ||= note_store.listNotebooks(token[:oauth_token])
>     note_filter = Evernote::EDAM::NoteStore::NoteFilter.new
>     notesMetadataResultSpec = Evernote::EDAM::NoteStore::NotesMetadataResultSpec.new        
>     notebook_details = Array.new()
>     notebookArray = Array.new()        
>     notesMetadataResultSpec.includeTitle = true
>     notebooks.each do |notebook|          
>       note_filter.notebookGuid = notebook.guid
>       notes_metadata = note_store.findNotesMetadata(token[:oauth_token],note_filter,0,10,notesMetadataResultSpec)          
>       validnotes = notes_metadata.notes          
>       validnotes.each do |note| 
>         notebook_details << Array('noteTitle' => note.title, 'noteGuid'=>note.guid)
>       end
>     end
> ```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Evernote API key has two permission levels. http://dev.evernote.com/doc/articles/permissions.php

If that's the case, you can ask dev support to bump up to full access. http://dev.evernote.com/support/faq.php#getsupport

Otherwise, please provide a bit more details like errors you got, code snippet, and so on.

Comment: Thanks @kentaro for your response, actually I'm not sure if the error I'm getting is due to a permission related issue, I have posted the error though in my original post.

Comment: Could you provide code snippet that I can see how you call findNotesMetadata?